# How download exe files with ChromeDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, selenium-chromedriver

I try to download exe files via ChromeDriver. But I see the following message: "This type of files can harm your computer..."
How I can avoid this message?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that we can switch off those messages in Chrome.

But i have a workaround.

1) chrome://settings/ --> Downloads --> Select the "Ask where to save each file before downloading" check box. Then every time before downloading a file chrome will ask you where to save the file & the default location is "Downloads" folder.

2) Write an AutoIt script just to press ENTER (As the focus is already on the popup).

Send("{ENTER}")

3) Once you click on the Download link, Run the above AutoIt Script using below command:

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Path of the AutoIt executable");

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to download files. It will shows such error for .js, .exe, .dll, excel macro files etc.
Things need to remember is when you try to install the software with any installer when you double click the exe file it will show you publisher name. If publisher is unknown it may possible that exe file is altered.

Most of the trusted software publishers use [Code Signing Certificate](https://codesigningstore.com) to validate their software package. This way software shows their company name as a publisher, and assure that the software is not altered.